# What is a 'canonical representation' of a field meant to be for equals() method (Joshua Bloch)

Tags: java, equals

In chapter 3, item 8:

```
public final class CaseInsensitiveString {
    private final String s;

    public CaseInsensitiveString(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString &&
            ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s.equalsIgnoreCase(s);
    }
    // remainder omitted
}
```

After describing issues surrounding the `equals()` method, he goes on to talk about this class in the context of comparing fields.

> For some classes, such as CaseInsensitiveString above, field comparisons are more complex than simple equality tests. If this is the case, you may want to store a canonical form of the field, so the `equals()` method can do cheap exact comparisons on these canonical forms rather than more costly inexact comparisons. This technique is most appropriate for *immutable* classes; if the object can change, you must keep the canonical form up-to-date.

So my question (and I double-checked what 'canonical' means): what is Bloch talking about? What would the canonical form be? I'm ready to be told that the answer is very simple (presumably otherwise his editor would have told him to add more) but I want to see other people say so.

He also mentions the same thing for `hashCode()` in the next item 9.

To give it in context, he also discusses a bad version of the `equals()` method for `CaseInsensitiveString`:

```
// Broken - violates symmetry
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString)
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase(
            ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s);
    if (o instanceof String) // one-way interoperability!
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase((String) o);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should add another `final` field and store value `s.toUpperCase()` for it.
This new field will be **canonical representation** `s` field. New implementation of method `equals()` (see code bellow) will be cheaper. This approach will work only for immutable classes.

Another point you should not forget override `hashCode()` if you override `equals()`.

```
public final class CaseInsensitiveString {

  private final String s;
  private final String sForEquals; //field added for simplifier equals method

  public CaseInsensitiveString(String s) {
      if (s == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(); //NullPointerException() - bad practice
      }
      this.s = s;
      this.sForEquals = s.toUpperCase();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString &&
          ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).sForEquals.equals(this.sForEquals);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
      return sForEquals.hashCode();
  }
  // remainder omitted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The term **canonical** has some different usages. It refers to values that have several representations (or maybe several varying values that are equal). Then often one specific representation (or value) is chosen as canonical one.

Example: Sets of integers: canonical { 2, 3, 5 } = { 3, 5, 2 } = { 2, 2, 5, 3 } = .... .

For the plain java String there is as issue too. The same text in Unicode can be represented differently: `ĉ` either as one code point `"\u0109"`SMALL-LETTER-C-WITH-CIRCUMFLEX, or as two code points `c` SMALL-LETTER-C and a zero-width `^` COMBINED-DIACRITICAL-MARK-CIRCUMFLEX (`"\u0063\u0302"`).

So even a plain String should be canonicalized in some cases:

```
String s = "...";
String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
```

This uses [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to decompose a string. This has the advantage, that one could **sort** and "c" and "ĉ" stay together. One could remove the combining diacritical marks with a regex and would have an ASCII version.

In fact different operating systems handle Unicode names differently, and not always version control systems respect a cross-platform canonicalisation.

Only after a `Normalizer.normalize` a comparison with `String.equals` indeed indicates Unicode text equality.

Answer (score 0):

Your question had two parts:

Canonical form means "standardised form - in this case a lowercase version of the field, used for comparison. Every time the value changes, the lowercase copy would have to be updated, so there's an overhead to this design choice. Further, this idea is an optimization for performance only, and frankly is not recommended as it's "premature optimisation"

Non symmetry of equals allows code such that `a.equals(b)` but not `b.equals(a)`, thus violating the equals contract. In your example, it's possible for a `String` to be equal to an instance of your class, because its `equals()` method allows that, but the implementation of `equals()` in the String class does not allow for an instance of your class to be considered as equal to a `String`.